# Iterating over alphabet tabs on a website to scrape data from alphabetically ordered pages using jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

What is the best way to iterate over the alphabet pages of the website given in the code below? Should I use the keywords string and iterate over it and append keyword to url or should I extract urls from the alphabet button toolbar on the first page? I tried both cases in the code below and get a null pointer exception. Please help.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String[] keywords = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
            String keyword = "a";
            //for (String keyword : keywords){
                String url = "http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/brand-index.asp?alpha="+keyword; 
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Element alphabetList = doc.select("div.class.btn-group.btn-group-sm").first();
                Elements alphabets = alphabetList.select("a[href]");
                for (Element alphabet : alphabets){
                    System.out.println("link : " + alphabet.attr("href"));
                    System.out.println("text : " + alphabet.text());

                }
}
```

**EDIT**

I figured how to do this correctly. However i get a read timeout error as this may not be the most efficient way to scrape so many pages. Suggestions welcome to improve code efficiency.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String,String> drugLinks = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        final int OK = 200;
        String currentURL;
        int page = 1;
        int status = OK;
        Connection.Response response = null;
        Document doc = null;
        String[] keywords = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        //String keyword = "a";
        for (String keyword : keywords){
            final String url = "https://www.medindia.net/drug-price/brand-index.asp?alpha="+keyword; 
            while (status == OK) {
                currentURL = url +"&page="+ String.valueOf(page); 
                response = Jsoup.connect(currentURL)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                        .execute();
                status = response.statusCode();


                if (status == OK) {
                    doc = response.parse();

                    Element table = doc.select("table").get(1);

                    for (Element rows : table.select("tr")) {
                        for (Element tds : rows.select("td")) {
                            Elements links = tds.select("a[href]");
                            for (Element link : links) {
                                drugLinks.put(link.text(), link.attr("href"));
                                System.out.println("link : " + link.attr("href"));
                                System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                page++;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Check what jsoup is getting for example via System.out.println(doc.text()); It is not what you are expecting. Either because website load its content via javascript (Jsoup can only get static html) or because it prevents from crawling some other way.

Comment: @Luk thanks so much for your response. I figured the answer. Posting it as an edit to my question. Now the issue I am encountering is 'Read timeout errors'. Is there a way to make this code more efficient or use multithreading to read pages?